# How to resolve populate with different field instead of _id in MoleculerJS

Tags: moleculer

I am creating a service to query Tasks collection from the MongoDB. It have a custom id field called uId, and a task store other uId of other taks in its field named subtask. I want to populate the field subtask, the task model is this  [task model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpbhL.png)

I expect to populate the field subtask with uId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `idField` in your service:

```js
{
  settings: {
    idField: "uId"
  }
}
```

[Documentation reference](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.13/moleculer-db.html#Settings)